# Java comparison of array data regardless of size or order

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a basic program to compare the data in two arrays. The order doesn't matter and neither do repeated numbers. The output is currently saying the array data is the same. Which is not what I want to happen as the array data is different. This is the code I have right now:

```
public class Algorithm1{
public static void main (String[] args){

    int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3};
    int[] array2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int matchCount = 0;
    boolean match = false;

for(int j = 0; j < array1.length;j++)   {
    for(int i = 0; i < array2.length;i++){
if(array1[j] == array2[i])
    matchCount++;


    }
}
if(matchCount >= array1.length && matchCount >= array2.length)
    match = true;

if(match = true){
    System.out.println("The data in the arrays is the same.");
                }
else if(match = false){
    System.out.println("The data in the arrays is different.");
                }
}
}
```

Comment: So what you want is to check if an array is a subset of the other?

Comment: @user3435566 your can try to sort it before.. that way its of O(nlogn) faster.. while using two for loops it would be O(n^2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace `if(match = true)` by `if(match == true)` or, even simpler, `if(match)`, and you should be all right ;)

You wrote:

```
if(match = true) {
    System.out.println("The data in the arrays is the same.");
}
```

That `if(match = true)` actually:

- sets `match` to `true`
- tests if the previous expression was `true`... and enters the `if` :)

---

As a side note, I would like to point out that you don't need to specify if(match==false) in your `else` clause... because if we enter that `else`, it already means that `match != true` (i.e.: `match == false`).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple error that a lot of begginning programmers make. When comparing two objects, you use `==` and when setting, you use `=`

Instead of:

```
if(match = true){
    System.out.println("The data in the arrays is the same.");   
}
else if(match = false){
    System.out.println("The data in the arrays is different.");
}
```

Should be:

```
if(match == true){
    System.out.println("The data in the arrays is the same.");   
}
else if(match == false){
    System.out.println("The data in the arrays is different.");
}
```

Well, in reality, it is very redundant. Saying `if(match == true)` is the same thing as just saying `if(match)` and no matter what, in the `else` part, if match is not true, then it must be false, so saying `else if(match == false)` is unnessesary. You only need to say `else`.

Here is what it should be with the revisions I have made:

```
if(match){
    System.out.println("The data in the arrays is the same.");   
}
else{
    System.out.println("The data in the arrays is different.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an approach you can utilize on the library. [Collections.indexOfSubList(List source, List target](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

```
public int findArray(Integer[] arg1, Integer[] arg2)
{
    return Collections.indexOfSubList(Arrays.asList(arg1), Arrays.asList(arg2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know if you need more explanation if this is what you need

O(nlogn) runtime if your are interested :) if you use a hash or set.. it will be O(n) but higher space complexity

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 3};
        int[] array2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 4,6};
        java.util.Arrays.sort(array1);
        java.util.Arrays.sort(array2);
        boolean match = true;
        int ptr1 = 0;
        int ptr2 = 0;
        while(ptr1<array1.length && ptr2<array2.length && array1[ptr1]==array2[ptr2])
        {

            ptr1++;ptr2++;
            while(ptr1<array1.length && array1[ptr1]==array1[ptr1-1])
            {
                ptr1++;
            }
            while(ptr2<array2.length && array2[ptr2]==array2[ptr2-1])
            {
                ptr2++;
            }
        }
        if((ptr1 == array1.length) && (ptr2 == array2.length))
            System.out.println("The data in the arrays is the same");
        else
            System.out.println("The data in the arrays is the different");
    }
}
```